# iOS message composer view inside titanium application

Tags: iphone, ios, titanium, appcelerator, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

Currently I'm using the following code to display the message composer, but it opens the native iOS message app and my application goes to background.

```
Titanium.Platform.openURL('sms:'+e.rowData.value);
```

But I want to show the message composer inside my application.

Is there any way to display the message composing window of iOS in my titanium application ?

I searched a lot but didn't get any solution. And there is nothing in the [appcelerator documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI) regarding the message composer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried with the Post share by Rahul.
Ti.Platform.openURL('sms://' +123456789 + '&body=' + encodeURIComponent("Test Message")); Worked for me too.

Comment: @DarshanaPatil: Are you sure that the solution provided will open the message window inside our own app ? Or just it open up the message app of iOS system ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently(January 1st 2013) no built-in modules available in Titanium SDK to integrate native iOS SMS view to Titanium application. There are a lot of third party modules for doing this.

1. [**TiSMSDialog**](https://github.com/omorandi/TiSMSDialog)
2. [**benCoding.SMS**](https://github.com/benbahrenburg/benCoding.SMS)

Also I developed a module for doing this, You can find it here [**MMP_SMS**](https://github.com/Midhun-MP/MMP_SMS).

Answer (score 3):

I have better solution without using module

Ti.Platform.openURL('sms://' +Your_phone_number + '&body=' + encodeURIComponent(MESSAGE_IN_STRING));

It worked for me.

Comment: Are you sure that the solution provided will open the message window inside our own app ? Or just it open up the message app of iOS system ?

Comment: It will open up the message app of the iOS system.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var SMS = require('ti.sms');
var sms = SMS.createSMSDialog({
    animated: true
});
sms.barColor = 'black';
sms.toRecipients = [
    '5678309' // who should receive the text? put their numbers here!
];
sms.messageBody = 'This is a text message.';
sms.addEventListener('complete', function(evt) {
    if (evt.success) {
        alert('SMS sent!');
    }
    else {
        switch (evt.result) {
            case SMS.CANCELLED:
                alert('User cancelled SMS!');
                break;
            case SMS.FAILED:
            default:
                alert(evt.error);
                break;
        }
    }
});
sms.open();
```

Comment: This won't work, because you are using any other module other than titanium for displaying the message window (That's why you are using require('ti.sms'))

Comment: Is it possible to select a contact from your list rather than prepopulate a phone nr?